# Vue3 shared props between components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-props, vue-options-api

I've recently switched from `Vue2` to `Vue3` but I'm sort of confused to what the best practice is to **shared** `props` between multiple components. I want to make input components which share the common `props` like "type", "name", etc. Previously I did it with `mixins` but I wonder if this still is the best way to do so.

Let me give an exampleof what I tried via the `options-api`:

```js
// Home.vue
<template>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>{{ type }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { sharedInputProps } from '../admin/composables/sharedInputProps'

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        ...sharedInputProps,
    },
    setup() {
        return {
        }
    },
})
</script>
```

```
// sharedInputProps.ts
import { ComponentPropsOptions } from 'vue'

export const sharedInputProps: ComponentPropsOptions = {
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'text',
    }
}
```

This works but I get no typehinting/autocompletion in my IDE to what the props are in `Home.vue` (in this case `<p>{{ type }}</p>`.

This is how I would do it with mixins:

```js
// Home.vue
<template>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>{{ type }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import InputProps from '../admin/mixins/InputProps.vue'


export default defineComponent({
    mixins:[
        InputProps,
    ],
    setup() {
        return {
        }
    },
})
</script>
```

```js
// InputProps.vue
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: 'text',
        }
    },
})
</script>
```

This works as intended and it gives me proper typehinting/autocompletion.

But I wonder how this should be done with the `composition-api` using the `defineProps` method. I got it to work directly defining the props in `Home.vue` with typehinting/autocompletion, as shown below:

```js
// Home.vue
<template>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>{{ type }}</p>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, withDefaults } from 'vue'
interface Props {
    type?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    type: 'text',
})

</script>
```

But as the documentation (https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props) states, it cannot be loaded from an external file.

So my question is, since using an external file with the `composition-api` is not supported (yet?) and an external file using the `options-api` and using the `spread` operator to destructurize an object is not giving typehinting/autocompletion, is `mixins` still the best practice to share props? Or am I misconfiguring something in my `sharedProps.ts` file (or somewhere else)?

I'm running the latest version of Vue 3(`3.2.47`) and I'm using the latest version of PHPStorm(`2023.1`) as my IDE.

Comment: You're discarding prop types with ComponentPropsOptions. Is there a problem with not using this type? I expect sharedInputProps to be the right move here

Comment: Glad it worked. `satisfies` may help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentPropsOptions` type prevents `sharedInputProps` to be implicitly typed.

If `sharedInputProps` are supposed to be compatible with `ComponentPropsOptions` type, it's possible do use `satisfies` in TypeScript 4.9 or higher:

```
export const sharedInputProps = {
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'text',
    }
} satisfies ComponentPropsOptions
```

This keeps the correct type when it's used as `props: { ...sharedInputProps }` and allows to spot an error in place where it's defined if it's incorrect.